# usage of 不有 in the Lost in Russia movie

Tags: grammar

There is a phrase 你不有钥匙吗? in the opening scene of the Lost in Russia movie (https://youtu.be/C78nLZZCVxc?t=191). Why 不有 and not 没有 is used here?

Answer (score 7):

In verbal conversation, "你不()有钥匙吗?" = "你不"**是**"有钥匙吗? - Don't you have the key?" It implies that you supposedly have one, but for some reason, usually because of carelessness, you didn't carry it.

While similar to the above, the question "你没有钥匙吗?" sounds milder and less accusative.

Comment: Just add on a reword in english that I think conveys the tone change:  "you are not in a state of having the key with you?"   we may not really say it that way in english, but it shows that implication they are totally capable of having the key and just don't currently.  The 沒有 version is just nuetral have or don't have with no such implication, you can answer no to it and maybe you never have had a key at all.

Answer (score 3):

你不有鑰匙嗎？is short for 你不[是]有鑰匙嗎？(Don't you have the key?)

People often omit words from commonly used phrases in daily conversation.

For example, It is very common to see people omitting 不可 in "為什麼非要聽你說不可?" and write "為什麼非要聽你說?" Since [非要...不可] is a set structure that people are familiar with, omitting half of it would not stop people from getting what it meant

[不是...嗎?] is also a familiar set structure, omitting "是" wouldn't make its meaning go away

"你不[是]有鑰匙嗎？" = "Don't you have the key?"

"你没有鑰匙嗎?" = "You don't have the key?"

Another example:

[若不...就會...]

若不吃藥就會死 --> 不吃藥會死

Answer (score 2):

有点“阴阳怪气”或者“反话”的感觉，在口语中。
要想理解`不`，还需要结合语境。比如去食堂回宿舍路上，室友要买零食或者小吃时候，就可以说“你不（语气上重一点，停顿一下）吃东西了吗？”（ní **bú** chī dōng xì le mǎ）